# Asterisk 11 GotoIf Comparison of Integers

Tags: comparison, asterisk

I can not get GotoIf() to properly compare two integers.

```
 exten => _X.,n,Set(junky=${RAND(0,1000)})
 exten => _X.,n,GotoIf(["${junky}"<"100"]?congest)
  ...
 exten => _X.,n(congest),Log(VERBOSE,"congested " ${EXTEN})
 exten => _X.,n,Congestion()
```

I have tried innumerable variations on the theme such as:

```
 exten => _X.,n,GotoIf([${junky}<100]?congest)
 exten => _X.,n,GotoIf(${junky}<100?congest)
 exten => _X.,n,GotoIf($["${junky}"<"100"]?congest)
```

...and nothing seems to work.  Each variation either goes to "congest" or not but it does it regardless of the value of junky.

Here we have an example of what we see in CLI:

```
-- Executing [26343434@ts-in:3] Set("SIP/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-00000431", "junky=150") in new stack
-- Executing [26343434@ts-in:4] GotoIf("SIP/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-00000431", "0?congest") in new stack
```

What is the right syntax for doing this in Asterisk 11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you are providing is missing a dollar sign ($) before the opening bracket. It is also a good practice to add spaces between the operands (older versions of Asterisk may have problems parsing if not separated), it should look like this:

```
exten => _X.,n,GotoIf($[ "${junky}" < "100" ]?congest)
```

In the verbose you are providing, the evaluation returns false so the call will continue to the next priority (you can tell because there is a zero before the question mark in the GotoIf line):

```
-- Executing [26343434@ts-in:3] Set("SIP/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-00000431", "junky=150") in new stack
-- Executing [26343434@ts-in:4] GotoIf("SIP/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-00000431", "0?congest") in new stack
```

If the following priority fails (eg. a Dial) the call will continue to the next one and so on, so you will hit the congestion eventually.

I hope this helps you.

Edit:

I made an example in my server, it is running Asterisk 11.22, I removed the double quotes because we are working with integers:

```
exten => 998,1,Set(junky=${RAND(0,1000)})
 same => n,GotoIf($[ ${junky} < 100 ]?congest)
 same => n,Playback(demo-congrats)
 same => n(congest),Hangup()
```

Here is an example where GotoIf returns false:

```
-- Executing [998@from-internal:1] Set("SIP/1001-00009821", "junky=999") in new stack
-- Executing [998@from-internal:2] GotoIf("SIP/1001-00009821", "0?congest") in new stack
-- Executing [998@from-internal:3] Playback("SIP/1001-00009821", "demo-congrats") in new stack
-- <SIP/1001-00009821> Playing 'demo-congrats.ulaw' (language 'es')
-- Executing [998@from-internal:4] Hangup("SIP/1001-00009821", "") in new stack
```

Since it returns false, the dialplan will continue, it will play the file demo-congrats and then hangup

Here is an example where GotoIf returns true:

```
-- Executing [998@from-internal:1] Set("SIP/1001-00009834", "junky=1") in new stack
-- Executing [998@from-internal:2] GotoIf("SIP/1001-00009834", "1?congest") in new stack
-- Goto (from-internal,998,4)
-- Executing [998@from-internal:4] Hangup("SIP/1001-00009834", "") in new stack
```

Since the evaluation returns true the call goes to the congest label skipping the playback.

I think the problem was in the quotes, try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that doesn't work for some reason.  That was the same as my 3rd example of failed code albeit without the spaces.  And it still fails.  BUT, I noticed something.  On cycle where junky was 0 the expression evaluated to TRUE, but if junky is anything but 0 the expression evaluates to FALSE.

Comment: Adding to the weirdness.  There is a similar expression with EXACTLY the same syntax (using Marco's version) except that it is > "950" which does work as expected.  So, in summary  junky < "100 only evaluates to true if junky is 1, but junky > "950" works as expected.  Sounds like a bug to me.